# How to call anonymous functions in chrome developer tool?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Here is my code:

```js
(function(params) {
  function sayHi(text) {
    console.log(text);
  }
  sayHi("Hello world")
})()
```

How can I call the sayHi() function from chrome developer tools ?

Comment: `window.sayHi = function sayHi(text) {` but makes not much sense to pollute the global scope.

Comment: `sayHi` isn't anonymous!

Comment: The whole point of the outer anonymous function is to *prevent* you from calling the inner function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sayHi` is scoped to the IIFE it is declared inside.

You can therefore only call it:

- From the same scope
- From a scope you copy the function to

## From the same scope

You need to move the scope of the Chrome Console into the function. You can do this by adding a breakpoint inside the IIFE (via the Sources panel) and then causing the IIFE to rerun by reloading the page.

Then you can call the function as normal.

[image: Animation showing how to add a breakpoint]

## Copy the function to a different scope

This requires that you edit the source code. The general way to do this is by returning a value from the IIFE.

```js
const sayHi = (function(params) {
  function sayHi(text) {
    console.log(text);
  }
  sayHi("Hello world");
  return sayHi;
})()

sayHi("This can now be called from outside the function, if this is the global scope it will be accessible to the Chrome Console");
```